# Delete rows from a dataset

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset built from a call to SemanticImport("/data.csv", Delimiters -> ",") with data.csv of the form:

```
Src, Dst, Size, Arrival, Delay, SrcClk, TrgClk, Nhops, Route, SrcErr, TrgErr
12, 22, 100, 1199145666.72, 10.483, 2107, 107, 12, 7774334, 0.002, 0.048
12, 22, 100, 1199145696.88, 10.42, ffff, 107, 12, 7774334, 0.002, 0.048
....
```

I would like to erase rows whose column called "SrcClk" has some bad values (ie, values different than "2107"). I've tried doing this with `DeleteCases` such as :

```
DeleteCases[d,  "SrcClk" != 2107]
```

with no success. `DeleteCases` expects a list, not a dataset so I guess it's the problem but I don't know how. While looking for an answer, I found many answers added a "&" at the end of their query but I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please add a small sample of your data to the question.

Comment: @mattator It's not mentioned particularly well on the Dataset help pages but take a look the Query function of which dataset[some function] is a special case of.  Also have a look at Slot which #name is a shorthand for which will explain the &.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are intermixing syntax for patterns and functions. `DeleteCases` expects a pattern, but you do provide (half of) a function (the other half is the missing `&`). You probably really should look into the documentation for `DeleteCases`, `Select` and `Function` to understand why and when a `&` is mandatory. On the other hand to delete from a `Dataset` you'd typically use the new `Query` syntax specifically made for them: `d[Select[(#SrcClk=!=2107)&]]`, which you'll find in the documentation for `Dataset`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should make a dataset query that uses `Select` to extract those rows which satisfy the predicate `#SrcClk == 2107 &`, a pure function that select those rows for which it evaluates to `True`. In a dataset or an associations. This notation is documented in the last example under Examples in [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).

```
keys = {"Src", "Dst", "Size", "Arrival", "Delay", "SrcClk", "TrgClk", "Nhops", "Route", 
  "SrcErr", "TrgErr"};
vals = {{12, 22, 100, 1199145666.72, 10.483, 2107, 107, 12, 7774334, 0.002, 0.048},
        {12, 22, 100, 1199145696.88, 10.42, ffff, 107, 12, 7774334, 0.002, 0.048}};
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread /@ (Rule[keys, #] & /@ vals)]
```

[image: dataset]

```
ds[Select[#SrcClk == 2107 &]]
```

[image: reduced]

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to be aware of, ffff in your example won't be treated as a string unless you enclose it with "" otherwise it will be treated as a symbol simplistically a variable that hasn't had a value set.  So looking at @m_goldbergs example some usual approaches won't work.  Am I right in suspecting the ffff is hexadecimal?

```
ds[Select[#SrcClk != ffff &]]  (* won't work *)
```

as

```
Head[ds[[2, "SrcClk"]]]  (* give *symbol* *)
```

First we can update the symbol to text, one way to do this is

```
ds = ds[{2 -> (<|#, "SrcClk" -> "ffff"|> &)}]  (* we can update value directly *)  

(* or we can update its Head  from Symbol to String *)  

ds1 = ds[{2 -> (<|#, "SrcClk" -> Apply[String, #"SrcClk"]|> &)}]
```

Also note that operations on a dataset are non-destructive until you update ds with "ds=" or create a new dataset ds1 with ds1=

A couple of other version of dataset selects I find useful

```
 ds[Select[#SrcClk == "ffff" && #Dst == 22 &]]   (* && is an AND operator *)
 ds[Select[#SrcClk == "ffff" || #Dst == 22 &]]  (* || is OR  *)
```

If we make the Dataset SrcClk column all of type of Head String then we can use wilds cards with StringMatchQ

```
ds1 = ds[{1 -> (<|#, "SrcClk" -> "2107"|> &)}]  
ds1[Select[StringMatchQ[#"SrcClk", "fff*"] &], {"Src", "Nhops", "SrcClk"}]
```

In the last example we have also included the optional selection of only 3 of the dataset keys.

Comment: There was indeed a problem with the types, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `DeleteCases`, then the following works. I have borrowed the prior formulation to set up the dataset, and use @m_goldberg "keys" and "ds" variables. Thank you.

```
delL = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[_, Length[keys]], 6 -> s_ /; ToString[s] != "2107"]
delA = AssociationThread[keys -> delL]
DeleteCases[ds, delA]
```

A couple of comments: first the temporary variables are here to make it clearer. Not pretty but show the intermediate results. Second the magic number 6 for the ReplacePart could be done by indexing into the keys list, but it just makes things bushier.

Finally, the FullForm of `ds` shows that the type of SrcClk is AnyType, because the data for the column has both the number 2107 and the string ffff. The `ToString` in the `Conditional` forces this conversion.